# question regarding convolution theorem

Tags: matlab, convolution, frequency-domain

As per the convolution theorem, a convolution in time domain is equivalent to a
multiplication in the frequency domain.

Then say (MATLAB code),

```
x = x(1:256)
y = y(1:256)
conv(x,y) should be equal to ifft(fft(x).*fft(y))
```

But it is not. Why is it so? What is that I am missing?

Comment: Do you about linear convolution versus circular or cyclic convolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see **help conv** (especially third parameter) and **help fft**. Valid code sample:

```
x = zeros(1,256); x(120:170)=1;
y = zeros(1,256); y(120:170)=1;
z = conv(x,y,'SAME'); size(z)
z1= ifft(fft(x).*fft(y));
z2 = real(fftshift(z1));
plot(z2);
```

Answer (score 0):

fft and ifft take finite length inputs and produce a same-length result, thus do circular convolution, not linear convolution.  Linear convolution produces a longer result.